# Python3 File Parsing - Re-open File?

Tags: python-3.x, parsing

I created a Python2 web scraper some years back and wanted to get back into using the language. As an avid Splunk user I wanted to write something that reads a Splunkd.log (Like the grep command). Then pulls only ERROR and WARN messages to a new file. Later I want to filter further into issues I know I would want to know about and copy them to the top of the file. For now I have it set up and printing all ERROR and WARN lines to a new file it creates called SplunkdFilterd.txt.I think the proper way to copy and bring the lines to the top is to 1. Close the files 2. Re-open in append mode 3. Seek to the top 4. Write the line(s).

I am having issues with re-opening or I'm going about this completely wrong. Any tips or ideas? Thank you for you time!

This is the error Python sends back:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kurt/python/SplunkdError&Warn.py", line 19, in <module>
    for line2 in Append1:
io.UnsupportedOperation: not readable
```

Code  I added a comment at line 19 to jump to easier:

```py
import sys

with open('splunkd.log','r') as InFile:
 with open('SplunkdFilterd.txt' , 'w+') as OutFile:
  for line1 in InFile: # Loop every line
    if 'ERROR' in line1: # Search for ERROR in line
        #print(line) # Print line
        OutFile.write(line1)
    elif 'INFO' not in line1: # Remove INFO lines
        #print(line) # Print line
        OutFile.write(line1)

InFile.close()
OutFile.close()

with open('SplunkdFilterd.txt' , 'a') as Append1:#Append already created file
 for line2 in Append1:       #This is line19#
    if 'Connection' or 'Connect' or 'Cert' or 'Certification' or 'AuthenticationManagerLDAP' in line:
        ##content = SplunkdFilterd.read()
        Append1.seek(0)
        Append1.write(line2)
        ##SplunkdFilterd.write(line.rstrip('\r\n') + '\n' + content)

        #
        #The above code filters out ERROR and WARN messages from splunk.log in
        #the same floder where the script is ran. It will create the SplunkdFiltered.txt
        #if the file is already created it will overwrite the file and not append.
```

Comment: If you want to add lines to the top of a file you have to re-write the whole file.  Append only works by adding to the end of a file.  It's not called `Prepend` 

Comment: A file opened with the append flag is not readable, you cannot iterate over it

Comment: @IainShelvington FYI, `'a+'` opens for reading and appending.

Comment: @MarkTolonen That did let it complete the script! I have done something else wrong since it didn't do what I though or anything at all really. Nothing added to the beginning or end of the file. Thank you for that info!

Comment: In append mode writes always seek to the end of the file first.  in `a+` you can seek back to the beginning and read, but the next write seeks back to the end again.

Comment: @MarkTolonen True, iterating over a file and writing to it is fairly complex... unless the OP is comfortable seeking to the correct position in the file

Comment: Not recommending it, just pointing out it's possible   There's still only one file pointer, so you either read or write...mixing would require saving file positions and yes, get complex.

Comment: @MarkTolonen I have this line to seek to the top of the file Append1.seek(0) or that is my hope and first try.

Comment: @Kurt You can't do what you want efficiently.  Add lines to the end of the file; or read the entire file in, seek back to the beginning, write the new line, and write the rest of the file back out.  Not very efficient.

Comment: @MarkTolonen Bottom it is. If I can't get it to display properly later on then I will just have it print two files or something.

Comment: @MarkTolonen I removed the seek line and it still didn't bring anything back. So I have more than one issue haha.

Comment: @Kurt Note also the two `.close()` are not necessary.  Exiting the `with` blocks closes the files.

Comment: @Kurt For what you want you need to read the whole file in, sort out the lines the way you want, then write the whole file out again.  You can't "move lines to the bottom", just add new lines to the bottom.  And in that case, you could put the lines at the top if re-writing the whole flie in a new sort order anyway 

Comment: @MarkTolonen okay so I need to do this all at once and not one step at a time. That makes sense I thought I may just go about it the wrong way at first. I got rid of both .close(). Now I get an error that I am operating on a closed file. Not sure why I get this after getting rid of any file close statements. 

  File "/home/kurt/python/SplunkdError&Warn.py", line 16, in <module>
    for line1 in OutFile:
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.

Comment: Looks like it was from using the same names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lines have to be sorted in memory to prioritize certain errors to the top.  Below will store lines in memory inserting where necessary.

Given splunkd.log:

```
some line1
some line2
ERROR unrelated
ERROR Connection
INFO line1
INFO line2
some line3
some line4
```

This:

```py
import sys

lines = []

with open('splunkd.log') as InFile:
    for line in InFile:
        if 'ERROR' in line:
            if any(s in line for s in ('Connect','Cert','AuthenticationManagerLDAP')):
                lines.insert(0,line) # important errors to front
            else:
                lines.append(line)   # other errors to end
        elif 'INFO' not in line:
            lines.append(line)       # non-INFO lines to end as well

with open('SplunkdFilterd.txt','w') as OutFile:
    OutFile.writelines(lines)
```

Produces SplunkdFilterd.txt:

```
ERROR Connection
some line1
some line2
ERROR unrelated
some line3
some line4
```